# Could a vacuum valve be responsible for a P1110 code on 2001 Saab 9-5 2.3T with check engine light on?

Tags: saab, 9-5, turbocharger, p1110

All of my monitors are in ready mode, only a <kbd>P1110</kbd> code left, for which I have installed booster pipe O-ring, new booster valve or hooter valve, my only culprit left is the vacuum valve on firewall, and I did order a new vacuum valve.

However, I believe in Murphy's Law and don't know if that is my last choice to fix <kbd>P1110</kbd> code or any suggestions would be greatly appreciated?? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure as to what you mean by booster valve. Do you mean the charge air bypass valve?

P1110 Charge Air Bypass Valve (CABV) performance fault.

Either the diaphragm in the bypass valve is bad.
The vacuum supply line to the bypass valve is bad.
Or the bypass valve solenoid/wiring has a fault.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes.

It's usually a fault in the connecting control hoses, the solenoid valve or the bypass valve. The bypass valve is a common failure on these vehicles

Answer (score 1):

I've replaced the turbo bypass valve twice on my '02 9-3SE B205R, once at 9x,xxx and again at 18x,xxx miles.  https://www.esaabparts.com/saab/parts/4441895  On several occasions I've had to find the vacuum hose that fell off the vacuum valve on the firewall, usually because I bumped it (https://www.esaabparts.com/viewparts.php?searchpart=1&section=311049379) but I'm still on the original of that part.  So, in this order: (1) find and reconnect the vacuum line that fell or got bumped off, often near the firewall; (2) replace all vacuum lines, 4mm ID; (3) test bypass valve and replace if failing; (4) test the vacuum valve at the firewall, then ask how you got this far down the list and whether it's really something else.